# How can I write a Typescript factory method to avoid the `new` keyword?

Tags: typescript

I enjoy Scala's case-class syntax, particularly elimination of the `new` keyword during instantiation. I'd like to do something similar in Typescript:

```
// Pizza.ts
class Pizza {
  constructor(name: string)
  bake(): string { return `delicious ${name} pizza` }
}

export default function(name: string) { return new Pizza(name) }
```

```
>> Pizza('pineapple').bake()
'delicious pineapple pizza'
```

This works fine. But what if I try to define a generic method for doing this operation on any class?

```
// AdvancedTechnology.ts
export function newless<C>(c: {new(...args: any[]): C}) {
  return function(...args: any[]): C { return new c(...args) }
}
```

```
// Pizza.ts
class Pizza { ... }
export default newless(Pizza)
```

This also works, but does not correctly preserve the type of the `Pizza` class; the compiler no longer knows about the `bake` method.

Is there a way to write `newless` so that the resulting class has the correct type?

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](https://tsplay.dev/NnXVeW)... the compiler knows about `bake()`.  Could you provide a [mre] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE, or barring that a configured web IDE project that demonstrates what you're seeing?